# hover events are blocked when select2 dropdown is open

Tags: hover, jquery-select2, dropdownbox

When a Select2 dropdown is open, the JavaScript hover event and the css pseudoclass do not work anymore.
E.g.

```
p:hover {
  color: red
}
```

only has effect when the dropdown is closed and not when it's opened.

See here for self contained example: http://jsfiddle.net/cre5hckw/6/

This may be related to https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1715.

I'm looking forward to any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Select2 uses a class, not :hover pseudoclass.

```
.select2-results .select2-highlighted {
    color: red;
}
```